# Openshift nodejs application takes forever to build

Tags: node.js, openshift, redhat

Anyone know why this happens. Even after taking forever, build always fails resulting in this error.

```
An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for
/var/lib/openshift/5388e99b5973cabeab00028f/nodejs
```

**Update:**

```
{
  "name": "epublica",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.5.1",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongoose":"*",
    "xml2js":"*",
    "component":"*",
    "nano":"*",
    "node-mysql":"*",
    "nodesql":"*",
    "adm-zip":"*",
    "archiver":"*",
    "consolidate":"*",
    "oauth":"*",
    "ejs":"*",
    "oauthorize":"*",
    "passport":"*",
    "passport-local":"*"
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "node-dev":"*",
    "phantomjs":"*",
    "mocha-phantomjs":"*",
    "grunt":"*",
    "should":"*",
    "testacular":"*",
    "gulp":"*",
    "browserify":"*",
    "gulp-browserify":"*"
  }
}
```

here is the package.json file for the code to be deployed in open shift.

**npm error log returned from rhc console**

```
Creating application 'kawee' ...
The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s
/bin/sh 538985745973ca14a5000015 -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon
'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c4,c809' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive
--init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' exceeded timeout of 231

.Last 10 kB of build output:
ET https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/defined
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parents
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path-browserify
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shallow-copy/0.0.1
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/subarg/0.0.1
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/syntax-error
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/timers-browserify
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tty-browserify
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/umd
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/url
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vm-browserify
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/process
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/util
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insert-module-globals
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/module-deps
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/os-browserify
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/browser-pack
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/browser-resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/console-browserify
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/querystring-es3/0.2.0
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET
https://registry.npmjs.org/querystring-es3/-/querystring-es3-0.2.0.tgz
npm http 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/querystring-es3/-/querystring-es3-0.2.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/builtins
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/constants-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-stream
npm info shasum c365a08a69c443accfeb3a9deab35e3f0abaa476
npm info shasum
/tmp/npm-506365-z0NCbPa0/1401521778328-0.6313501968979836/tmp.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-zlib
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/crypto-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commondir/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deps-sort
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domain-browser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer/-/buffer-2.1.13.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/https-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/events
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/derequire
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/defined
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer/-/buffer-2.1.13.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/parents
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shallow-copy/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/syntax-error
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/subarg/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/timers-browserify
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 03:36:18
npm http GET
https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify/-/stream-browserify-0.1.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vm-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/umd
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tty-browserify
npm info shasum c88838ebf79f30b8b4a707788470bea8a62c2355
npm info shasum
/tmp/npm-506365-z0NCbPa0/1401521778527-0.5179499718360603/tmp.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/url
npm info
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
ulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify
unbuild
npm info preuninstall browserify@3.46.1
npm info uninstall browserify@3.46.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/insert-module-globals
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/process
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert
npm http 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify/-/stream-browserify-0.1.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/util
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 03:36:19
npm info postuninstall browserify@3.46.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/module-deps
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browser-pack
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browser-resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/umd/-/umd-2.0.0.tgz
npm info shasum 95cf1b369772e27adaf46352265152689c6c4be9
npm info shasum
/tmp/npm-506365-z0NCbPa0/1401521778981-0.4455321067944169/tmp.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/os-browserify
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/umd/-/umd-2.0.0.tgz
npm info shasum 749683b0d514728ae0e1b6195f5774afc0ad4f8f
npm info shasum
/tmp/npm-506365-z0NCbPa0/1401521779184-0.7841910272836685/tmp.tgz
npm info
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
ulp-browserify
unbuild
npm info preuninstall gulp-browserify@0.5.0
npm info uninstall gulp-browserify@0.5.0
npm info postuninstall gulp-browserify@0.5.0
npm info shasum 11582258d74f7f6ed720c59112cee3e29c18c09a
npm info shasum
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/.npm/querystring-es3/0.2.0/package.t
gz
npm info shasum 45e17d4ccf79c2301601ef166f423daf5ba0b97e
npm info shasum
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/.npm/umd/2.0.0/package.tgz
npm info shasum 7d175cbf4b2aa006c975ba57c42d15cfe208a4c8
npm info shasum
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/.npm/stream-browserify/0.1.3/package
.tgz
npm info preinstall esprima@1.0.4
npm info build
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/esprima
npm info linkStuff esprima@1.0.4
npm info install esprima@1.0.4
npm info postinstall esprima@1.0.4
npm info shasum 7fee432215b274b84a3338a489b17348ae128ddf
npm info shasum
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/.npm/underscore/1.4.4/package.tgz
npm info install underscore.string@2.3.3 into
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse
npm info install underscore@1.4.4 into
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse
npm info installOne underscore.string@2.3.3
npm info installOne underscore@1.4.4
npm info
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse/node_modules/underscore.string
unbuild
npm info
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse/node_modules/underscore
unbuild
npm info preinstall underscore@1.4.4
npm info build
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse/node_modules/underscore
npm info linkStuff underscore@1.4.4
npm info install underscore@1.4.4
npm info postinstall underscore@1.4.4
npm info preinstall underscore.string@2.3.3
npm info build
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse/node_modules/underscore.string
npm info linkStuff underscore.string@2.3.3
npm info install underscore.string@2.3.3
npm info postinstall underscore.string@2.3.3
npm info build
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse
npm info linkStuff argparse@0.1.15
npm info install argparse@0.1.15
npm info postinstall argparse@0.1.15
npm info build
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt/node_modules/js-yaml
npm info linkStuff js-yaml@2.0.5
npm info install js-yaml@2.0.5
npm info postinstall js-yaml@2.0.5
npm info build
/var/lib/openshift/538985745973ca14a5000015/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/g
runt
npm info linkStuff grunt@0.4.5
npm info install grunt@0.4.5
npm info postinstall grunt@0.4.5
```

Comment: can you post your package.json?

Comment: @user3351722 i just included my package.json config if that helps

Comment: first of all, change "scripts/starts" to something like that:

"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"

Comment: if this dont work please look for any errors in you build-process and post it (openshift use a old npm version- often this is the problem)

Comment: after changing the start script, i am now getting...Server returned an unexpected error code: 504. Its still takes forever to build the project though so it is safe to assume that my request timed out. @user3351722

Comment: Openshift take very long on build every time. What you Console say (openshift-webseite)? If you timeout out at the git pull request, please post your error - sometimes you have to change you ssh-settings

Comment: You have to post the hole build-log. It should print after "git push".

Please use http://gist.github.com if it's very long and provide a link.

Comment: I'm running "rhc app create appName nodejs-0.10 <giturl>"  from my windows command prompt and i'm getting back Server returned an unexpected error code: 504  after a long wait. How can i access the build log? do i have to ssh to  my openshift box and get this? @user3351722

Comment: Try to create a fresh openshift "rhc app create appName nodejs-0.10". Than git-clone the app to your local file system, add a files of your application and run "git push". Than you see the complete build system

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the npm install locally and adding your npm_modules directory to git and doing a git push, that way it does not have to try to download, build, install all of the dependencies and time out, that is what was done for the ghost blog quickstarts.